# How do I install IBM i Access for Mac?

Tags: macos, telnet, ibm-midrange

IBM now has *IBM i Access for Mac*, with 5250 emulator being a very desirable feature, but the default install approach isn't the "Mac way" where users would expect it to exist in `/Applications`.  How can I get it installed like a normal Mac app with an icon/application in the `/Applications` folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what worked for me.  First download the zip file from [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/solutions.html)

Open up Mac's Terminal app (`Cmd+Space` and type `Terminal`)

cd into where the zip file now exists:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Use unzip to get the zip file contents into the `/Applications` folder:

```
unzip IBMiAccessT_v1r1.zip -d "/Applications/IBM i Access Client Solutions.app"
```

cd into the following folder where `acs_mac_app.zip` now exists:

```
cd /Applications/IBM\ i\ Access\ Client\ Solutions.app/Mac_Application
```

Now unzip the `acs_mac_app.zip` file into /Applications which will add content to `/Applications/IBM i Access Client Solutions.app`

```
unzip acs_mac_app.zip -d /Applications
```

You should now have "IBM i Access Client Solutions" with an icon in the /Applications folder, as shown below.  Double click to start or do Cmd+Spacebar to open Spotlight and type "ibm" to locate it, as shown below.

[image]

[image]